# Find tangent of path in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'd like to position svg elements (say, ellipses) along a path, for instance a curve generated with a d3.js [line generator with B-spline interpolation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#line). While finding the coordinates of points along the path is easy using path.getPointAtLength(), I can't figure out how to find the tangent of any point on the line. If I could get the tangent (or the derivative), I would be able to rotate the elements accordingly to make them look as if they are positioned along the line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call path.getPointAtLength() at two points close together. Calculus tells us the difference is the slope/tangent at that point.